# Final toolbar item icon not showing

Tags: c++, winapi, toolbar

I am wrapping the Win32 toolbar. Everything works except that whenever the user of the wrapper class adds a separator, the last toolbar item's icon does not show.

Consider this client code:

```
    toolbarBtn tbb[] = { toolbarBtn { ID_FILE_NEW, IDI_NEW },
                            toolbarBtn { ID_FILE_OPEN, IDI_OPEN },
                            sep { },
                            toolbarBtn { ID_FILE_SAVEAS, IDI_SAVE },
                            toolbarBtn { ID_FILE_PRINT, IDI_PRINT },
                            sep { },
                            toolbarBtn { ID_EDIT_UNDO, IDI_UNDO },
                            toolbarBtn { ID_EDIT_REDO, IDI_REDO } };

this->tb = toolbar { *this, tbb, sizeof tbb / sizeof *tbb };
```

The `toolbarBtn` objects represent a toolbar button. The `sep` object is a separator, and inherits from class `toolbarBtn`. The following statement calls the constructor of the toolbar class, creating it. For this code, this is what I get as graphics output:

[image]

As you can see by hover, the final two buttons exist! But for a reason icon does not show, and the order is also changed of the icons. It should be "New", "Open", [Separator], "Save", "Print", [Separator], "Undo", and "Redo". But "Save As" and "Redo" do not show. And I know that the icon itself is not problem, because i can put any sequence of `toolbarBtn`s, but as long as there is a `sep` object, then the last icon never displays.

Here is a implementing of relevant functions/methods:

```
toolbarBtn::toolbarBtn(int id, icon ico, BYTE state, BYTE style)
{
    ZeroMemory(this, sizeof *this);
    this->ico = ico;
    this->tbb.idCommand = id;
    this->tbb.fsState = state;
    this->tbb.fsStyle = style;
    this->tbb.iBitmap = 0;  // field will be changed by toolbar c'tor
}

// count # of buttons; no separators counted
size_t nActualButtons(const toolbarBtn btns[], size_t n)
{
    size_t n1 = n;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (btns[i].getTBB().fsStyle & TBSTYLE_SEP)
            --n1;
    return n1;
}
toolbar::toolbar(overlappedwindow parent, const toolbarBtn btns[], size_t n, 
                 int id)
{
    this->hwnd = CreateWindow(TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, 
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBSTYLE_FLAT, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        parent.gethwnd(), (HMENU) id, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if (this->hwnd == NULL)
        message(L"%s: %s", __FUNCTIONW__, geterror());

    // Send the TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE message, which is required for
    // backward compatibility.
    SendMessage(this->hwnd, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);

    HIMAGELIST imglist = ImageList_Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR32, n, 0);
    if (!imglist)
        message(L"%s: %s", __FUNCTIONW__, geterror());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (btns[i].getTBB().fsStyle & TBSTYLE_SEP)
            continue;     // dont add separators to image list
        if (ImageList_AddIcon(imglist, btns[i].getIcon().gethandle()) == -1)
            message(L"%s: %s", __FUNCTIONW__, geterror());
    }

    SendMessage(this->hwnd, TB_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) imglist);

    TBBUTTON *tbb = (TBBUTTON *) calloc(n, sizeof (TBBUTTON));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        tbb[i] = btns[i].getTBB();
        tbb[i].iBitmap = (tbb[i].fsStyle & TBSTYLE_SEP) ? 0 : i;
        if (tbb[i].fsStyle & TBSTYLE_SEP)
            tbb[i].idCommand = 0;
    }
    SendMessage(this->hwnd, TB_ADDBUTTONS, n, (LPARAM) tbb);
    free(tbb);
}
```

Comment: `nActualButtons` does not count the separartor. So, if you are using the return value from that to pass to the `toolbar` constructor, the loops in the constructor will terminate before processing the last item

Comment: @JimRhodes I'm not passing the return value from `nActualButtons` to the `toolbar` constructor. I'm passing the size of the array (`sizeof tbb / sizeof *tbb`). In fact, I'm not using `nActualButtons` anywhere in the code, idk why i even posted it

Comment: If you have two separators, will the two last images not show? Could you add the code that actually calls the function above?

Comment: @pingul the code that calls the function above is at the very top of the question. And to answer your question about the separators, if i add two separators, it is still only the final item that does not appear.

Comment: @pingul i apologize, the final TWO do not display if i add two separators

Comment: Oh, I missed it. However, that call only has 3 arguments while the function below has 4. Am I missing something? And, is there a reason for using low level memory allocation instead of `std::vector` and the like? Estimating the length of an array by `sizeof arr/sizeof *arr` always scares me a little.

Comment: The final argument of `toolbar::toolbar` is optional, and im just using a plain array because im not going to be changing its size or anything, just reading from it @pingul

Comment: That's why we use `std::array`. Anyways, I don't think we can infer from the code what's causing the problem -- normal debugging seems to be the way to go. I'd post this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com for some code improvements, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem may be with this:

```
sep { },
```

Your are essentially doing this:

```
sep {0, 0, 0, 0}
```

So your separator will not have TBSTYLE_SEP set. You should probably initialize the separator like this:

```
sep {0, 0, 0, TBSTYLE_SEP}
```

Comment: My separator class just inherits from the `toolbarBtn` class, and its constructor calls that of `toolbar`: `sep() : toolbarBtn(0, icon { }, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_SEP) { }`.